# ASP.NET MVC2 Application goes into error state after period of time

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, stack-trace

After a period of time (exact time undetermined) our MVC app starts to error with the error message and stack trace below.

We are not registering any custom ViewEngines...touching the web.config file clears this error up for awhile.

What could I be missing?

```
[InvalidOperationException: The property 'MasterLocationFormats' cannot be null or empty.]
   System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.GetPath(ControllerContext controllerContext, String[] locations, String[] areaLocations, String locationsPropertyName, String name, String controllerName, String cacheKeyPrefix, Boolean useCache, String[]& searchedLocations) +697
   System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, String viewName, String masterName, Boolean useCache) +288
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass6.<FindView>b__4(IViewEngine e) +43
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.Find(Func`2 cacheLocator, Func`2 locator) +96
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult.FindView(ControllerContext context) +144
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +153
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass14.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__11() +33
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +613
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +613
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +613
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +613
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +263
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +709
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +162
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4() +58
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +20
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +469
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +375
```

Answer (score 0):

One idea may be that repository instance is being reused. Make sure that new instance is created for repository having method that is populating `MasterLocationFormats` property.